# why won't the back button appear given this code (UINavigationController question)

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview, uibarbuttonitem

Can't seem to get the Back Button to appear in a UINavigationController flow.  I just want it to trigger the pop'ing of the current controller automatically to get back to the parent.

I'm getting a little confused in terms of what the minimum necessary is to get an automatic back button (I mean the one with the title of the parent controller and a button that has an arrow pointing back to the left), and what you then need to do to custom things beyond this.  I'm just searching for the former at this stage.

```
@implementation AppointmentListController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"Detailed View";
    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:nil action:nil];
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
    [backButton release];
}
```

The code to get to this view (i.e. code in parent controller):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     AppointmentListController *appointmentListController = [[AppointmentListController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AppointmentListController" bundle:nil];
     [ [self navigationController] pushViewController:appointmentListController animated:YES];
     [appointmentListController release];
}
```

EDIT: PS with the code above I actually don't see any button at all appear on the left.

EDIT2: David, I tried button the following backbutton code in the RootViewController (and pulled it out of the AppointmentListController), however it still doesn't show any sort of back button?

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:nil action:nil];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
[backButton release];
```

EDIT3: David - Did work actually with the following code, except that the text was "back" and not the title of the parent controller like I'm after - tried deleting the .title= line but then no button appeared.

```
// create a custom navigation bar button and set it to always say "Back"
UIBarButtonItem *temporaryBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init];
temporaryBarButtonItem.title = @"Back";
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = temporaryBarButtonItem;
[temporaryBarButtonItem release];
```

EDIT4 - by bad - I hadn't set the title of the parent controller so I guess in this case it doesn't try to but a back button up at all - so adding "self.title = @"Views";" to the parent controller fixed things (and removing the line where I was manually setting the back button tittle)

EDIT5 - for anyone who was confused like me - so in the end you don't need any of the backBarButtonItem setting code in the Parent controller at all - just had to make sure the parent controller had a "title" set and then things seem to work automatically - doh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The back button refers not to the top controller, but the second-of-controller stack controller. You put the back button on your detailViewController. You should have put it on your UITableViewController.

Comment: David, I tried button the following backbutton code in the RootViewController (and pulled it out of the AppointmentListController), however it still doesn't show any sort of back button?  Put the code in the EDIT2 area that I tried

Comment: David - tried again and this worked must have made a mistake first time - put the code I used in the main post for reference

Comment: Oh..only thing I noted was that the text was "back" and not the title of the parent controller - I tried removing the temporaryBarButtoItem.title= line however this still didn't work, there was no button at all when I did this

Comment: by bad - I hadn't set the title of the parent controller so I guess in this case it doesn't try to but a back button up at all - so adding "self.title = @"Views";" to the parent controller fixed things (and removing the line where I was manually setting the back button tittle)

Comment: by bad - I hadn't set the title of the parent controller so I guess in this case it doesn't try to but a back button up at all - so adding "self.title = @"Views";" to the parent controller fixed things (and removing the line where I was manually setting the back button tittle)

Answer (score 0):

The backBarButtonItem is what is displayed when the view controller is behind another view controller in a navigation stack.  In other words, if you were to push a view controller on top of it, instead of seeing "Detailed View" in the back button, it would be a cancel button.

To get the behavior you want, use leftBarButtonItem

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

Comment: I tred this Simon, and I did get a button then, but it was a normal CANCEL button.  It wasn't a back button with the title of the parent controller and a little left handle arrow pointing to the left as part of the button?

Comment: I am confused as to what you want the app to look like then, you set up the button to be a cancel button, but then you don't want it to be a cancel button?

Comment: sorry if I haven't been clear - I'm just trying to get the standard button on the left (for a UINavigationController) type flow that takes you back (or up one level of controller) - I see them in iPhone apps as a button but with a pointer arrow to the left as part of the button design - I'm really just trying to get one of these to appear & getting a little confused re what is the minimum you have to do in the scenario where you have a parent controller in a UINavigationController setup, then you pop the next child controller onto it

Answer (score 0):

At the time view did lOad is called the appropriate navigationbar is not On the stack, you should write the code in the viewdidappear method of UIViewController

Answer (score 0):

The back button appears automatic if you set your viewController title first (`self.title`).

Then if you push a view controller from a view controller having title "first view", the pushed one will has a back button with the label "first view".

If you don't set the title the automatic back button appear only on the third pushed view, not before.

```
firstController (title: "", back: NO) -> secondController (title: "", back: NO) -> thirdController (title: "", back: YES)
```

I don't know if it's a bug or they wanted it. I read the UINavigationController guide lines but doesn't see nothing about it.